# How to find pressure when you are given radius and area.

Tags: calculus

Consider a vertical piston/cylinder system. The piston has 50 g mass and a given radius of 3 cm. What is the pressure due to the piston?

Can someone please help me with this question in a step by step answer. I am really confused :/

Comment: Have you already tried to solve the problem?
At what point you are stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Just think to the formula for pressure:
$$
P=\frac {F_\perp}{S},
$$
where $F_\perp$ is the perpendicular component of the force acting on the surface and $S$ is the surface's area.

In this case $F_\perp=P=mg$ and the surface is the given circle.